# Strip all HTML from string, except <mark> tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a large string in javascript that I need to strip all the html, minus specific tags.

I'm currently using

```
var noHTML = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
```

Now this strips the html, what regex can I add to ignore mark tags while doing this?

Comment: Obligatory reference to http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/221867

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, regex isn't the really the right tool to use for parsing HTML. That being said, one way to do this is to use a look ahead for the tags you want to keep:

```
var noHTML = /(?!(<ul|<\/ul>))(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
```

In this example, "ul"

so specific to your case:

```
var noHTML = /(?!(<mark|<\/mark>))(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
```

You can see it working here in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0xgs0u9m/

You may also want to instead consider using something like html parser on npm:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmlparser

From their example:

```
var handler = new Tautologistics.NodeHtmlParser.DefaultHandler(function (error, dom) {
    if (error)
        [...do something for errors...]
    else
        [...parsing done, do something...]
});
var parser = new Tautologistics.NodeHtmlParser.Parser(handler);
parser.parseComplete(document.body.innerHTML);
alert(JSON.stringify(handler.dom, null, 2));
```

Results in:

```
[ { raw: 'Xyz ', data: 'Xyz ', type: 'text' }
  , { raw: 'script language= javascript'
  , data: 'script language= javascript'
  , type: 'script'
  , name: 'script'
  , attribs: { language: 'javascript' }
  , children: 
     [ { raw: 'var foo = \'<bar>\';<'
       , data: 'var foo = \'<bar>\';<'
       , type: 'text'
       }
     ]
  }
, { raw: '<!-- Waah! -- '
  , data: '<!-- Waah! -- '
  , type: 'comment'
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the JS implementation of php's [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

[JS `strip_tags` (from the phpjs project)](http://phpjs.org/functions/strip_tags/)

```
function strip_tags(input, allowed) {
  allowed = (((allowed || '') + '')
    .toLowerCase()
    .match(/<[a-z][a-z0-9]*>/g) || [])
    .join(''); // making sure the allowed arg is a string containing only tags in lowercase (<a><b><c>)
  var tags = /<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>/gi,
    commentsAndPhpTags = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->|<\?(?:php)?[\s\S]*?\?>/gi;
  return input.replace(commentsAndPhpTags, '')
    .replace(tags, function($0, $1) {
      return allowed.indexOf('<' + $1.toLowerCase() + '>') > -1 ? $0 : '';
    });
}
```

**Usage**

```
var x="<html><body>something in <b>bold</b> <mark>mark <i>italics</i> </mark>";
console.log(strip_tags(x,"<mark>")); //"something in bold <mark>mark italics </mark>"
```